# Net monitor for UDP connection

Tags: c++, dll, plugins, monitor

I want to make a little net monitor program. Microsoft function `GetTcpTable2` it's very good with useful examples. It is what I need, can find each program to make a net connection. Can be extended with no problem for IPV6.

My problem's on UDP monitor connections. Using `GetUdpStatisticsEx2` can I find the process too but only the local address, more important it's a remote address, and cannot get it.

How to can get a remote address by UDP?

I tried this code, but stuck to UDP:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>

// Need to link with Iphlpapi.lib and Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
/* Note: could also use malloc() and free() */

bool getName(DWORD pid) {
  DWORD name_size;
  char filename[MAX_PATH];
  HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
  if (hProcess) {
    name_size = GetModuleBaseNameA(hProcess, NULL, filename, MAX_PATH);
    filename[name_size] = '\0';
    printf("getName: %s\n", filename);
    char process[255];
    sprintf(process, "|%s|", filename);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

int main() {
  // Declare and initialize variables
  PMIB_TCPTABLE2 pTcpTable;
  ULONG ulSize = 0;
  DWORD dwRetVal = 0;

  char szLocalAddr[128];
  char szRemoteAddr[128];

  struct in_addr IpAddr;

  int i;

  pTcpTable = (MIB_TCPTABLE2 *) MALLOC(sizeof (MIB_TCPTABLE2));
  if (pTcpTable == NULL) {
    printf("Error allocating memory\n");
    return 1;
  }

  ulSize = sizeof (MIB_TCPTABLE);
// Make an initial call to GetTcpTable2 to
// get the necessary size into the ulSize variable
  if ((dwRetVal = GetTcpTable2(pTcpTable, &ulSize, TRUE)) ==
      ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
    FREE(pTcpTable);
    pTcpTable = (MIB_TCPTABLE2 *) MALLOC(ulSize);
    if (pTcpTable == NULL) {
      printf("Error allocating memory\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }
// Make a second call to GetTcpTable2 to get
// the actual data we require
  if ((dwRetVal = GetTcpTable2(pTcpTable, &ulSize, TRUE)) == NO_ERROR) {
    printf("\tNumber of entries: %d\n", (int) pTcpTable->dwNumEntries);
    for (i = 0; i < (int) pTcpTable->dwNumEntries; i++) {
      printf("\n\tTCP[%d] State: ", i,
             pTcpTable->table[i].dwState);
      switch (pTcpTable->table[i].dwState) {
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSED:
        printf("CLOSED\n");
        break;
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_LISTEN:
        printf("LISTEN\n");
        break;
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_SYN_SENT:
        printf("SYN-SENT\n");
        break;
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_SYN_RCVD:
        printf("SYN-RECEIVED\n");
        break;
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB:
        printf("ESTABLISHED\n");
        break;
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT1:
        printf("FIN-WAIT-1\n");
        break;
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_FIN_WAIT2:
        printf("FIN-WAIT-2 \n");
        break;
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSE_WAIT:
        printf("CLOSE-WAIT\n");
        break;
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSING:
        printf("CLOSING\n");
        break;
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_LAST_ACK:
        printf("LAST-ACK\n");
        break;
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_TIME_WAIT:
        printf("TIME-WAIT\n");
        break;
      case MIB_TCP_STATE_DELETE_TCB:
        printf("DELETE-TCB\n");
        break;
      default:
        printf("UNKNOWN dwState value\n");
        break;
      }
      IpAddr.S_un.S_addr = (u_long) pTcpTable->table[i].dwLocalAddr;
      strcpy_s(szLocalAddr, sizeof (szLocalAddr), inet_ntoa(IpAddr));
      printf("\tLocal Addr: %s", szLocalAddr);
      printf(" : %d \n", ntohs((u_short)pTcpTable->table[i].dwLocalPort));

      IpAddr.S_un.S_addr = (u_long) pTcpTable->table[i].dwRemoteAddr;
      strcpy_s(szRemoteAddr, sizeof (szRemoteAddr), inet_ntoa(IpAddr));
      printf("\tRemote Addr: %s", szRemoteAddr);
      printf(" : %d \n", ntohs((u_short)pTcpTable->table[i].dwRemotePort));

      printf("\tOwning PID: %d\n", pTcpTable->table[i].dwOwningPid);
      getName(pTcpTable->table[i].dwOwningPid);

      ULONG rosSize = 0, rodSize = 0;
      ULONG winStatus;
      PUCHAR ros = NULL, rod = NULL;
      rodSize = sizeof(TCP_ESTATS_DATA_ROD_v0);
      PTCP_ESTATS_DATA_ROD_v0 dataRod = { 0 };

      MIB_TCPROW row;
      row.dwLocalAddr = pTcpTable->table[i].dwLocalAddr;
      row.dwLocalPort = pTcpTable->table[i].dwLocalPort;
      row.dwRemoteAddr = pTcpTable->table[i].dwRemoteAddr;
      row.dwRemotePort = pTcpTable->table[i].dwRemotePort;
      row.dwState = pTcpTable->table[i].dwState;

      if (row.dwRemoteAddr != 0) {
        if (rosSize != 0) {
          ros = (PUCHAR)malloc(rosSize);
          if (ros == NULL) {
            printf("\nOut of memory");
            return 0;
          }
          else
            memset(ros, 0, rosSize); // zero the buffer
        }
        if (rodSize != 0) {
          rod = (PUCHAR)malloc(rodSize);
          if (rod == NULL) {
            free(ros);
            printf("\nOut of memory");
            return 0;
          }
          else
            memset(rod, 0, rodSize); // zero the buffer
        }
        winStatus = GetPerTcpConnectionEStats((PMIB_TCPROW)&row, TcpConnectionEstatsData, NULL, 0, 0, ros, 0, rosSize, rod, 0, rodSize);
        dataRod = (PTCP_ESTATS_DATA_ROD_v0)rod;
        printf("\tBytesIn: %d, BytesOut: %d\n", dataRod->DataBytesIn, dataRod->DataBytesOut);

      }
    }
  }
  else {
    printf("\tGetTcpTable2 failed with %d\n", dwRetVal);
    FREE(pTcpTable);
    return 1;
  }

  MSG msg;
  while (1) {
    GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  if (pTcpTable != NULL) {
    FREE(pTcpTable);
    pTcpTable = NULL;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

### Completed:

It seems like the only way is to use winsock. I will take the pid and name process as well the IP:port (the connection socket). In winsock recv procedure will check if match IP:port and I will complete the data missing.

I have another problem now. I want to get more of the process pid and name, I need to find out what **module** (of the dlls loaded by the process) makes the net connection.

Comment: GetUdpTable also doesn't have any way to get remote address info.

Comment: I say this too but what it's the solution ? Are a lot of program which monitorize UDP and show the remote address.

Comment: UDP is connection-less, so no UDP table from the OS can provide any remote addresses, because there are no remote addresses being kept track of. The remote address is specified on a per-packet basis as a parameter to `sendto()` and related APIs. If you need the remote addresses, you will have to monitor the actual packets being sent, such as by using a capturing library like npcap.

Comment: Try winsock to see UDP packets or any builded app. I don't want to use any lib like npcap. This libs are based on win procedures.

Comment: UDP it's not so "connection-less" it's important.